# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.management.agent not found

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter, java-15

I am setting up my first Spring Boot application using Eclipse > New > Spring-Starter project
The project files are appearing and compiling.
I am even able to RunAs > Java project with console output.
On choosing RunAs > **Spring Boot**, I am getting the above error in the console:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.management.agent not found
```

1. My Java version is Java15, and I have also verified the same path is being used by Eclipse in About Eclispse > Installation Details > Configuration which shows
   `-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll`
2. Running `java --list-modules` shows the *management.agent* module in the list shown in the command line output:

```
jdk.localedata@15.0.1
jdk.management@15.0.1
jdk.management.agent@15.0.1
jdk.management.jfr@15.0.1
```

Maven version installed is 3.3.6

I am not sure what I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: to start off you can try upgrading the maven and eclipse version to the latest maintaining compatibility with Java-15.